# What is the order of Attributes in the result of the Query in DynamoDB (.net)?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

In .net I specify

```
QueryOperationConfig queryConfig = new QueryOperationConfig
{
Filter = queryFilter, 
IndexName = "PARTNAME-NAME-index",
Limit = 1, 
BackwardSearch = desc, 
Select = SelectValues.SpecificAttributes,
AttributesToGet = new List<string>
    { "PARTNAME","ID", "NAME","WEIGHT" }
};
```

But in Query results Attributes order is
WEIGHT, ID, PARTNAME, NAME

In my table PARTNAME is Hashkey, ID is Sortkey, and I have GSI PARTNAME-NAME-index combined of PARTNAME and NAME

How can I specify the needed Attributes order, 
or how how are they ordered by default?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are using the legacy `AttributesToGet` parameter.

> This is a legacy parameter. Use ProjectionExpression instead.

**Answer:-**

DynamoDB doesn't guarantee the order of the attributes in results. Primarily, DynamoDB is a **key-value store**. You need to get the value for the specific key from the result.

Please note that this is not like SELECT statement on RDBMS. This is a NoSQL database and it is completely different from RDBMS.

Comment: i get error: QueryOperationConfig doesn.t have definition for ProjectionExpression

Comment: Yes agreed, this class does't have this parameter. However, class Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model.QueryRequest class has parameter ProjectionExpression and clearly mentioned that it is a deprecated parameter. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html. Gets and sets the property AttributesToGet.
This is a legacy parameter. Use ProjectionExpression instead. For more information, see AttributesToGet in the Amazon DynamoDB Developer Guide.

Comment: Ugh, as I understand QueryRequest shoild be used like AmazonDynamoDBClient.Query(QueryRequest), and now I'm using table.Query(QueryOperationConfig). Everything in my function should be changed...